# What is better way to code a custom pop-view use xib

Tags: objective-c

What i have done in StePopView.m file so far is that :

```
+(instancetype)loadFromXib{
    return [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass(self) owner:nil options:nil][0];
}
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    //configure my view
    self.backgroundColor = [[UIColor colorWithWebStr:@"050205"] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.33];

}
//when move to superView, call show method to show a pop view with animation 
-(void)didMoveToSuperview{
    [self show];
}
-(void)show{
    //show a pop view with animation
}
```

When i use this pop-view  in superView:

```
StePopView* popView = [StePopView loadFromXib]; 
popView.frame.bounds = self.bouds;
[self addSubView:popView]
```

Is this a better coding ? And what`s the better code and why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what ever way you choose is the best way to do.

Comment: You should manage your popup with an own view controller.

Comment: I've tried it this way.@macmoonshine

Comment: what i meant is that is there other code about showing popView , i do this in -(void)didMoveSupperView method@VishalKalola